# Iterate id from the controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I iterate in the controller, I want to replace the view and create object an for `@reserve = Reserve.where(:user_id=>user.id)`, how can I get each user.id from `@user_list = User.where.not(id: 1)` and output the view as

```
<% @reserve.each do |a| %>
  <td><%= a.date %></td>
  <td><%= a.time %></td>
<% end %>
```

---

Model

```
class Reserve < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

View

```
<% @user_list.each do |user| %>

<td><%= user.name %></td>

<% Reserve.where(:user_id=>user.id).each do |a| %>
  <td><%= a.date %></td>
  <td><%= a.time %></td>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
@user_list = User.where.not(id: 1)
```

The reason why I want to do it this way is because I am using a gem for sorting 
and I want to place the sort on their respective model instead of using User for both reserve and user which would cause an error.

```
when /^created_at_/
      order("user.created_at #{ direction }")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question (which I'm not sure I do), in your controller, do something like:

```
@user_list.each do |user|
  @user = user
  @reserve = Reserve.where(user: user) # <= do some sorting around here
  render partial: 'user_list'
end
```

Now, you'll have `@user` and `@reserve` available in a partial, something like:

```
# _user_list.html.erb

<td><%= @user.name %></td>

<% @reserve.each do |a| %>
  <td><%= a.date %></td>
  <td><%= a.time %></td>
<% end %>
```